# difference between two consecutive rows in mysql

Tags: mysql

I have a table in MySQL database:

```
  id     ts            number
1   07-10-2017 00:00    200
2   07-10-2017 00:01    300
3   07-10-2017 00:02    700
4   07-10-2017 00:03    1000
```

I want to calculate difference between two consecutive rows and i need output format be like:

```
id        ts           number   o/p
1   07-10-2017 00:00    200      0
2   07-10-2017 00:01    300     100
3   07-10-2017 00:02    700     400
4   07-10-2017 00:03    1000    300
```

I want first value of o/p column to be 0 and rest is the difference.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: is that 7th October or 10th July?

Comment: @Strawberry The weather in London is usually lovely on both those days, so this isn't a probem here.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen You must be thining of north London. Come October, it gets pretty windy daan saaf.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do this with a local variable:

```
SET @tmp := -1;
SELECT id,
 ts ,
 number,
 if(@tmp =-1, 0, number - @tmp) as 'o/p',
 @tmp:=number as dummy
FROM YourTable
Order by ts;
```

Comment: This makes certain assumptions about ts which don't appear to be true (although they should be!)

Answer (score 10):

Use a self-join:

```
SELECT
    t1.ts,
    t1.number,
    t1.number - COALESCE(t2.number, t1.number) AS diff
FROM yourTable t1
LEFT JOIN yourTable t2
    ON t1.id = t2.id + 1
ORDER BY
    t1.ts;
```

[image]

### Demo

Comment: Thanks Tim. Using this query I am getting o/p = 100 for id =1 which I don't want.. Still thanks for the help..

Comment: @NikhilKumawat My query works fine, check the demo and screenshot.  You either copied it wrongly, or your data is not what you actually posted in your question.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen this answer is great and has multiple applications for me, particullarly around generating running totals and comparing sequential row values for error reporting. Avoids looping over the data in php (I'm wondering which is faster though). Thanks for sharing