# Is there a way to create auto filling tables in mysql?

Tags: mysql

```
+---------------------+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+
| dt                  | val1      | val2      | val3      | total     |
+---------------------+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+
| 2020-07-02 12:00:17 | 123317117 | 109962378 | 105746677 | 339026172 |
| 2020-07-02 12:01:18 | 123317269 | 109962533 | 105746841 | 339026643 |
| 2020-07-02 12:02:19 | 123317422 | 109962688 | 105747005 | 339027115 |
| 2020-07-02 12:03:20 | 123317574 | 109962843 | 105747169 | 339027586 |
| 2020-07-02 12:04:21 | 123317726 | 109962999 | 105747331 | 339028056 |
| 2020-07-02 12:05:22 | 123317877 | 109963153 | 105747492 | 339028522 |
| 2020-07-02 12:06:23 | 123318030 | 109963308 | 105747656 | 339028994 |
| 2020-07-02 12:07:23 | 123318182 | 109963464 | 105747820 | 339029466 |
| 2020-07-02 12:08:24 | 123318335 | 109963619 | 105747987 | 339029941 |
| 2020-07-02 12:09:25 | 123318487 | 109963774 | 105748153 | 339030414 |
| 2020-07-02 12:10:26 | 123318640 | 109963929 | 105748318 | 339030887 |
| 2020-07-02 12:11:26 | 123318792 | 109964085 | 105748482 | 339031359 |
| 2020-07-02 12:12:27 | 123318944 | 109964240 | 105748646 | 339031830 |
| 2020-07-02 12:13:28 | 123319096 | 109964395 | 105748808 | 339032299 |
| 2020-07-02 12:14:29 | 123319248 | 109964550 | 105748971 | 339032769 |
| 2020-07-02 12:15:30 | 123319400 | 109964705 | 105749134 | 339033239 |
| 2020-07-02 12:16:30 | 123319552 | 109964860 | 105749300 | 339033712 |
| 2020-07-02 12:17:31 | 123319704 | 109965015 | 105749466 | 339034185 |
| 2020-07-02 12:18:32 | 123319857 | 109965170 | 105749631 | 339034658 |
| 2020-07-02 12:19:33 | 123320009 | 109965325 | 105749795 | 339035129 |
| 2020-07-02 12:20:34 | 123320153 | 109965473 | 105749952 | 339035578 |
| 2020-07-02 12:21:34 | 123320305 | 109965627 | 105750114 | 339036046 |
| 2020-07-02 12:22:35 | 123320457 | 109965782 | 105750276 | 339036515 |
| 2020-07-02 12:23:36 | 123320609 | 109965937 | 105750438 | 339036984 |
| 2020-07-02 12:24:37 | 123320761 | 109966092 | 105750602 | 339037455 |
| 2020-07-02 12:25:38 | 123320913 | 109966246 | 105750768 | 339037927 |
| 2020-07-02 12:26:39 | 123321065 | 109966401 | 105750934 | 339038400 |
| 2020-07-02 12:27:39 | 123321218 | 109966556 | 105751098 | 339038872 |
| 2020-07-02 12:28:40 | 123321370 | 109966711 | 105751263 | 339039344 |
| 2020-07-02 12:29:41 | 123321522 | 109966867 | 105751426 | 339039815 |
| 2020-07-02 12:30:42 | 123321674 | 109967022 | 105751588 | 339040284 |
| 2020-07-02 12:31:42 | 123321827 | 109967176 | 105751751 | 339040754 |
| 2020-07-02 12:32:43 | 123321979 | 109967331 | 105751915 | 339041225 |
| 2020-07-02 12:33:44 | 123322130 | 109967487 | 105752079 | 339041696 |
| 2020-07-02 12:34:45 | 123322283 | 109967642 | 105752245 | 339042170 |
| 2020-07-02 12:35:45 | 123322435 | 109967797 | 105752411 | 339042643 |
| 2020-07-02 12:36:46 | 123322587 | 109967952 | 105752576 | 339043115 |
| 2020-07-02 12:37:47 | 123322739 | 109968108 | 105752741 | 339043588 |
| 2020-07-02 12:38:48 | 123322891 | 109968263 | 105752905 | 339044059 |
| 2020-07-02 12:39:49 | 123323043 | 109968419 | 105753067 | 339044529 |
| 2020-07-02 12:40:49 | 123323196 | 109968574 | 105753231 | 339045001 |
| 2020-07-02 12:41:50 | 123323348 | 109968729 | 105753395 | 339045472 |
| 2020-07-02 12:42:51 | 123323501 | 109968884 | 105753561 | 339045946 |
| 2020-07-02 12:43:52 | 123323653 | 109969040 | 105753727 | 339046420 |
| 2020-07-02 12:44:53 | 123323805 | 109969195 | 105753892 | 339046892 |
| 2020-07-02 12:45:53 | 123323957 | 109969350 | 105754056 | 339047363 |
| 2020-07-02 12:46:54 | 123324109 | 109969505 | 105754220 | 339047834 |
| 2020-07-02 12:47:55 | 123324261 | 109969660 | 105754381 | 339048302 |
| 2020-07-02 12:48:56 | 123324413 | 109969815 | 105754544 | 339048772 |
| 2020-07-02 12:49:56 | 123324565 | 109969970 | 105754708 | 339049243 |
| 2020-07-02 12:50:57 | 123324717 | 109970126 | 105754872 | 339049715 |
| 2020-07-02 12:51:58 | 123324869 | 109970281 | 105755038 | 339050188 |
| 2020-07-02 12:52:59 | 123325022 | 109970437 | 105755205 | 339050664 |
| 2020-07-02 12:54:00 | 123325174 | 109970592 | 105755370 | 339051136 |
| 2020-07-02 12:55:00 | 123325327 | 109970749 | 105755536 | 339051612 |
| 2020-07-02 12:56:01 | 123325478 | 109970904 | 105755700 | 339052082 |
| 2020-07-02 12:57:02 | 123325630 | 109971060 | 105755863 | 339052553 |
| 2020-07-02 12:58:03 | 123325783 | 109971216 | 105756027 | 339053026 |
| 2020-07-02 12:59:04 | 123325935 | 109971372 | 105756191 | 339053498 |
| 2020-07-02 13:00:04 | 123326087 | 109971527 | 105756357 | 339053971 |
+---------------------+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+
```

Hello,

I have the above table `values`, some data added to mysql every minute. I might have to add it faster though.

I want to know, if it is possible to create, and how to go about creating:

1. A table that takes the 1st value of the `total` column and subtracts it from the second value, the 2nd value from the 3rd, 3rd from 4th and so on, divided by 10.

```
    +---------------------+-----------+---------------------+-----------+---------+
    | date1               | t1        | date2               | t2        | diff    |
    +---------------------+-----------+---------------------+-----------+---------+
    | 2020-07-02 12:01:18 | 339026643 | 2020-07-02 12:00:17 | 339026172 | 47.1000 |
    +---------------------+-----------+---------------------+-----------+---------+
```

2. A table that takes the 1st entry of 1st hour and subtracts it from the 1st entry of the next hour. basically 01:00 - 00:00, 02:00-01:00 ... 24:00-23:00 divided by 10, and begins from 00:00 again after the day changes.

```
    +---------------------+-----------+---------------------+-----------+-----------+
    | date1               | t1        | date2               | t2        | diff      |
    +---------------------+-----------+---------------------+-----------+-----------+
    | 2020-07-02 13:00:04 | 339053971 | 2020-07-02 12:00:17 | 339026172 | 2779.9000 |
    +---------------------+-----------+---------------------+-----------+-----------+
```

It will be great if both tables will grow as the main tables adds data.

Thank you!

Comment: In MySQL there are things called Views. A View is like a query that once you create it, you can query it just like a table. The cool part is that since the View is a query and queries accept calculated fields, you can do this fairly easily. This also allows you to keep things exactly as they are and simply create the View.

Comment: Alternatively, you can just create a `SELECT` query with calculated fields based on adjacent fields within the same table or multiple tables.

Comment: Definitely take a look at this article MySQL Math Calculations https://www.brainbell.com/tutorials/MySQL/Performing_Mathematical_Calculations.htm

Comment: So should i use a view to loop through the `values` table, `total` column?

Comment: To get those 2 tables i did:
`select (select dt from values where DATE_FORMAT(dt, '%Y%m%d%H%i') like '202007021300') as date1,
 (select total from values where DATE_FORMAT(dt, '%Y%m%d%H%i') like '202007021300') as t1,
 (select dt from values where DATE_FORMAT(dt, '%Y%m%d%H%i') like '202007021200') as date2,
 (select total from values where DATE_FORMAT(dt, '%Y%m%d%H%i') like '202007021200') as t2,
 ((select total from values where DATE_FORMAT(dt, '%Y%m%d%H%i') like '202007021300') - (select total from values where DATE_FORMAT(dt, '%Y%m%d%H%i') like '202007021200'))/10 as diff;`

Comment: I have no clue how to apply a loop to that statement.

Answer (score 0):

I found a way to do it, and also managed to create a view for it.

I got help from this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50679773/difference-between-two-consecutive-rows-in-mysql):

Here is the code i used:

```
create view total_diff as
    SELECT
        t1.dt as t1_dt,
        t1.total as t1_total,
        t2.dt as t2_dt,
        t2.total as t2_total,
        t1.total - COALESCE(t2.total, t1.total) AS diff
    FROM values t1
    LEFT JOIN values t2
        ON t1.id = t2.id + 1
    ORDER BY
        t1.dt;
```

Thank you for the advice on views! Nifty trick.
After i found out how they work, i made a bunch of them, for different situations.