# Find max time difference between consecutive user transactions

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a user transactions table that look like the following:

```
USER_ID    TRANSACTION_ID     TIMESTAMP
user1      id1                2022-01-19 15:21:27.000
user1      id2                2022-01-20 15:21:27.000
user1      id3                2022-01-25 15:21:27.000
user2      id1                2022-01-18 15:21:27.000
user2      id2                2022-01-28 15:21:27.000
user2      id3                2022-01-29 15:21:27.000
```

I'd like to write a query that could find the max time difference between each user's transaction times (days is preferred but anything else would do it as well). For the above the desired output would be:

```
USER_ID     MAX_DIFF
user1       5 (time diff between id2 and id3)
user2       10 (time diff between id1 and id2)
```

I have thought about ordering rows based on `TIMESTAMP` then use an approach similar to one posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50679773/difference-between-two-consecutive-rows-in-mysql):

```
SELECT
    t1.ts,
    t1.number,
    t1.number - COALESCE(t2.number, t1.number) AS diff
FROM yourTable t1
LEFT JOIN yourTable t2
    ON t1.id = t2.id + 1
ORDER BY
    t1.ts;
```

Problem is that transaction ids in my table are random uuids and can not be used in such a fashion. Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: I see that in a comment under the answer you got you have a working solution. If it is what you need you should post it as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The query can use `LAG()` to peek at the previous row (according to any ordering) and compute the time difference. Then it can use `MAX` to find the maximum difference between rows:

For example:

```
  SELECT user_id, MAX(diff) AS max_diff
  FROM (
    SELECT *,
      TIMESTAMPDIFF(second, LAG(ts) 
        OVER(PARTITION BY user_id ORDER BY ts), ts) AS diff,
      LAG(transaction_id) OVER(PARTITION BY user_id ORDER BY ts) AS prev_tx_id
    FROM t
  )
  GROUP BY user_id
  HAVING max_diff IS NOT NULL
```

Comment: Thank you for your great answer. I had to make a minor change to make it work though. The diff for the first row is `NULL` and ordering by diff causes `NULL` value to become row number one, hence the query returns `NULL` as `max_diff`. The query that worked for me:
select user_id, MAX(diff)
  from (
    select *,
      timestampdiff(second, lag(ts) 
        over(partition by user_id order by ts), ts) as diff,
      lag(transaction_id) over(partition by user_id order by ts) as prev_tx_id
    from t
  ) x
group by user_id
. Let me know if I'm missing something here.

Comment: I have to mention that I'm running the above queries in Snowflake and not sure if that affects how those queries work.

Comment: @ahajib "...and ordering by diff causes NULL value to become row number one..." -- Good catch. I didn't see that detail. Your query works well too.

Comment: Perfect. Please update your answer so I could accept it as the solution to my question.

Comment: @ahajib Added `where diff is not null` to remove nulls.